# Super User requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load

Tags: discussion, javascript

In one occasion I tried to refresh my super user tab, I got this following error:

> Super User requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is
>   blocked or failed to load.

Can somebody explain more about it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make this an answer rather than a comment so this question can serve as an anchor for this issue.  The answer is the same as DavidPostill's answer to  [icons-missing-on-stack-exchange-sites](https://superuser.com/questions/840542/icons-missing-on-stack-exchange-sites).  SU somehow got on the Fanboys Social Blocking List and ad blockers give various problems like that JavaScript message or elements of the page missing. The solution is to disable ad and tracker blocking add-ons for the SU web site (in my case, AdBlock Plus and Ghostery).

Comment: At least in the case of AdBlock Plus, it is a fairly simple matter to find the offending filter list rule(s) and disable them. That add-on is far too valuable as a blocker/hider of some seriously annoying elements on SE sites to consider a blanket deactivation .